# Devise.secret_key was not set error when attempting to push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to push my project to heroku and I am getting the error below. I have already tried inserting the secret key into my devise.rb file and I am still unable to push my project. What could be the cause of this?

```
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:
remote:        
remote:          config.secret_key = '58216f7aa3031f4abcf97b44a526911b4aacf005ffd09c2243cc125d23a01b1d27e941ea4a627f33b6802d3ec821e55ffcf2f609ee570a98b4cb445ccbd29820'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you setup Devise it doesn't automatically have a secret key set. It's commented out.

If you take a look at the devise initializer `config/initializers/devise.rb` on line 11 you'll see something like this

```
# config.secret_key = 'token'
```

If you uncomment this and push to GitHub, then Heroku everything should push correctly.

Comment: I have uncommented it, pushed it to github, and I am still getting the same error when I try to push to heroku.

Comment: what Devise and Rails versions are you using @Alex?

Comment: rails 5.2.1 and devise 4.4 @John

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying where Devise should look for the secret key inside your `devise.rb` file:

```
config.secret_key = Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base
```

or

```
config.secret_key = Rails.application.secret_key_base
```

Comment: I tried both of these and i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you check this issue here please, @Alex: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4807